# How to add class to odd class "recensie" within section with class 'album_revieuws'

Tags: jquery

So i have this question.

I am wondering how i can add an class "selected"
to every odd class called recensie within the section with the class album_reviews only.

```
<section class="album_reviews">
    <h2 class="sectiontitel"> Album Reviews </h2>
    <article class="recensie">
      <h1> Neil Young – A Letter Home </h1>
      <img src="Images/Albums/A_Letter_Home.jpg" alt="album_image"/>
      <p>Earlier this year, Neil Young unveiled Pono, a super-high-def audio service meant to deliver us from the sonic crimes of the earbud era. For his next act, he's released an acoustic covers set recorded at Jack White's Nashville music shop on a Voice-O-Graph--a super-low-def 1940s contraption that looks like a phone booth and sounds a few steps removed from a rusty tin can and some twine. If it's meant as some kind of joke, here's the punch line: In its perverse way, A Letter Home is one of the most enjoyable records Young has made this century.</p>
      <p> 
        <a href="http://www.rollingstone.com/music/albumreviews/a-letter-home-20140502#ixzz33g0Hq3pw"> Read more </a>
      </p>       
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="band_members">
    <h2 class="sectiontitel"> Band Members</h2>
    <article class="recensie">
      <h1> Neil Young </h1>
      <figure>
          <img src="Images/Artists/Neil_Young.jpg" alt="Macaque in the trees">
          <figcaption> Neil Young <br /> Singer Songwriter </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>
  </section>
```

That's my HTML code.
I know how to add a class to only the odd's but not to only the odds within the section.album_reviews

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.album_reviews').find('.recensie:odd').addClass('selected');
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yM6RW/)

Comment: Actually i already found the answer but thanks. How ever you come most close to what i needed :) $("section.album_reviews").find("article.recensie:odd").addClass("selected");

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('.album_reviews .recensie:odd').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:odd` selector in jquery. It selects all odd elements

```
$("section.album_reviews .recensie:odd").addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Could you provide a little explanation of how your answer works?