# Jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to learn jQuery. I've been asked the following questions, but I'm unsure on the answers:

1. Add selected to figure elements that come after a `h1` element and are on the same level.

   My guess would be: `$("h1 figure").addClass("selected");`
2. Add selected to all uneven article elements with the class `recensie` that are in the class `album_reviews`.

   My thought: `$("#album_reviews #recensie article:odd").addClass("selected");`
3. Add selected to the last listitem element that are in the `ul` element with class: "sitemap"

   My thought: `$("ul#sitemap li").last().addClass("selected");`

I know this sound like homework assignments, but it's for personal training and I'm really stuck.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>wp22 tentamen van 13 juni </title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vraag1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Music Lovers</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
        <li> <a href="#">New Music</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Album Reviews</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Concert Reviews</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Community</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Login</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  

  
  <section class="album_reviews">
    <h2 class="sectiontitel"> Album Reviews </h2>
    <article class="recensie">
      <h1> Neil Young – A Letter Home </h1>
      <img src="Images/Albums/A_Letter_Home.jpg" alt="album_image"/>
      <p>Earlier this year, Neil Young unveiled Pono, a super-high-def audio service meant to deliver us from the sonic crimes of the earbud era. For his next act, he's released an acoustic covers set recorded at Jack White's Nashville music shop on a Voice-O-Graph--a super-low-def 1940s contraption that looks like a phone booth and sounds a few steps removed from a rusty tin can and some twine. If it's meant as some kind of joke, here's the punch line: In its perverse way, A Letter Home is one of the most enjoyable records Young has made this century.</p>
      <p> 
        <a href="http://www.rollingstone.com/music/albumreviews/a-letter-home-20140502#ixzz33g0Hq3pw"> Read more </a>
      </p>       
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="band_members">
    <h2 class="sectiontitel"> Band Members</h2>
    <article class="recensie">
      <h1> Neil Young </h1>
      <figure>
          <img src="Images/Artists/Neil_Young.jpg" alt="Macaque in the trees">
          <figcaption> Neil Young <br /> Singer Songwriter </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>
  </section>

<footer>
     <nav>
        <div>
           <h3>Sitemap</h3>
           <ul class="sitemap">
              <li> <a href="#">New Music</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Album Reviews</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Concert Reviews</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Community</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Links</h3>
        <ul class="links">
            <li> <a href="#">rollingstone.com</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">3voor12.vpro.nl</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">pitchfork.com</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">nme.com</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">allmusic.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <p> &copy;FHICT </p>
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't know why my answers are wong.

Comment: The documentation for jQuery selectors will help you. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors. You'll see straight away that `"h1 figure"` is not the correct way to select `figure`'s that come after `h1`'s. `"h1 figure"` is the descendant selector. You want the next sibling.

Comment: 1. `$("h1 + figure").addClass("selected");` - next sibling selector

Comment: `I know this sound like homework assignments, but it's for personal training and I'm really stuck.` Sounds like user Xereoth is doing same personal training...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284767/how-to-add-class-to-odd-class-recensie-within-section-with-class-album-revieu

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Technically, he wants prev sibling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer you:

1.

```
$("H1").nextAll("figure").addClass("selected");
```

2.

```
$(".album_reviews").find("article.recensie:odd").addClass("selected");
```

3.

```
$("ul.sitemap").find("li:last-child").addClass("selected");
```

#### Notice 'class' selectors start with "." and not with "#"

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I was wondering why the last answer isn't: $("ul.sitemap li").last().addClass("selected");? Oh sorry, I see I put the wrong question for the last one, could you take a look at it?

Comment: sure if it's the last element you can do .find("li:last-child").addClass... ** I'm pretty sure .last() will choose the absolute last element, and not each last element in a group like you wanted